# how to get image content and name from folder and save in database without form

Tags: php

Is there a way to take content and name of picture from folder and put it in to a database without using HTML form element. I've tried something like this

```
<?php

foreach(glob('*.png') as $img){

    print_r(file_get_contents($_FILES[$img]['tmp_name']));

    echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';

}
```

but when i tryed to take content the warning says:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstPHPprojekt\pictest.php on line 5

Comment: What the hell is `$_FILES[$img]['tmp_name'])`???  You're not uploading.

Comment: I think you are a little bit confused about $_FILES. However finfo_file could be of help (http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). The first example is very close to yours.